# How do add non-model fields to DRF's serializer response dict?

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

How do add one extra field (non-model field) to serializer.data dict ?  I would like to add ("status" : "available") before sending the response. I tried this    -

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    ## This one doesn't work as serializer.data is of the type 'ReturnDict' 
    serializer.data.append(("status","available")) 
    ## OR
    serializer.data["status"]  = "available"
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I also want to modify serializer.data's field names before sending the response. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can add an extra field to the serializer like this:

---

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_status')

    class Meta: 
        model = MyModel
        read_only_fields = ('status',)

    def get_status(self, obj):
        """ Get the current objects status """
        if obj.available == 1:
            return 'available'
        else:
            return 'not available'
```

---

One way to change the field names would be to use a middleware class to format the response. I would do this if I would have to format the response for the whole API.

Comment: Adding status field to the serializer will create problem with POST, while creating a new object. I do not have any field called 'status' in my model and I don't want it. So, serializing the POST request might create problem if I add status field here.

Comment: It won't create problems because you can set it as read only.

Comment: `class Meta:`

    `model = MyModel`
    `read_only_fields = ('status',)`

Comment: @norbert.mate you can edit your answer and add those details.